# Extract numbers in Javascript from multiple elements with same class

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, extract

I have different elements within my page with the same class.
All these elements contain a both text and numbers.
I need to extract all numbers from all elements.

e.g. I have the following elements:

```html
<div class="myelement">bla bla bla 123</div>
<div class="myelement">bla bla bla 456</div>
<div class="myelement">bla bla bla 789</div>
```

..and I need to extract 123, 456, 789 respectively.
Can you please help me out?

Thanks much in advance for your help.

Comment: You seem to know enough that you should use regex, so where are you stuck? Please show what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to find all numbers in your strings would be to use regex `/\d+/`:

```js
var strings = Array.prototype.map.call(
  document.getElementsByClassName('myelement'),
  function(element) {
    return element.innerText;
  }
);

var numbers = [];
var regex = /\d+/;

strings.forEach(function(item) {
  regex.exec(item).forEach(function(result) {
    numbers.push(+result); // convert to a number with + prefix
  });
});

console.log(numbers);
```

```html
<div class="myelement">bla bla bla 123</div>
<div class="myelement">bla bla bla 456</div>
<div class="myelement">bla bla bla 789</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is based of [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

- document.getElementsByClassName('myelement') returns an HTMLCollection
- for each element of this collection call the map function in order to convert each element to an array element
- for each single text return only the number

The result is an array.

```js
var result = [].map.call(document.getElementsByClassName('myelement'), function(ele, index) {
  return  ele.textContent.replace(/\D*/, ''); // remove all non digit
});
console.log(result)
```

```html
<div class="myelement">bla bla bla 123</div>
<div class="myelement">bla bla bla 456</div>
<div class="myelement">bla bla bla 789</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go about this:

```js
var results = []
els = document.getElementsByClassName('myelement');
[].forEach.call(els, function(el) {
    results.push(el.innerHTML.match(/\d+/)[0])
});
results.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<div class="myelement">bla bla bla 123</div>
<div class="myelement">bla bla bla 456</div>
<div class="myelement">bla bla bla 789</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, you can loop each myelement, split the string into chars, and use isNumeric to put the numbers in an array.

```
        var numbers = [];

        var vals = $('.myelement').each(function(i,v){

            var str = $(this).html();               
            var chars = str.split("");

            $.each(chars, function(i,v){
                if($.isNumeric(v)) numbers.push(v); 
            });
        });
```